# Unable to list graph permissions granted to the application from Java

Tags: java, azure-ad-graph-api

I want to get the list of graph permissions granted to an application using Java.

I am able to get the permissions from this code

```java
GraphServiceClient graphClient = GraphServiceClient.builder().authenticationProvider( authProvider ).buildClient();

OAuth2PermissionGrantCollectionWithReferencesPage oauth2PermissionGrants = graphClient.servicePrincipals("000xxxx-xxxx-40xx-b8xx-561247xxxxx").oauth2PermissionGrants()
    .buildRequest()
    .get();
```

In the output, I can see the permissions in the scope parameter. But I am getting only delegated permissions. Why am I not getting application permissions?

Is there a way to get application permissions too? Has anyone tried this and got it?

TIA

Comment: Does this answer your question [List appRoleAssignments granted to a service principal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/serviceprincipal-list-approleassignments?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=java#example)?

Comment: Have you tried by checking the permissions in graph explorer , to make sure , you are having application permission as well ? link - https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer

Comment: I'm sure I consented to application permissions in Portal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the below results:***

I registered one Azure AD application and granted **Application permissions** like below:

[image]

To get those **Application permissions** list, you can make use of below query:

```json
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/servicePrincipals/your_sp_objectID/appRoleAssignments
```

**Response:**

[image]

**Code sample in Java:**

```java
GraphServiceClient graphClient = GraphServiceClient.builder().authenticationProvider( authProvider ).buildClient();

AppRoleAssignmentCollectionPage appRoleAssignments = graphClient.servicePrincipals("000xxx-54xx-40xx-b8xx-56124xxxxxx").appRoleAssignments()
    .buildRequest()
    .get();
```

You can note the above **`appRoleId`** and check their ***names*** with below query:

```json
GET  https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/servicePrincipals?$filter=appId eq '00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000'&$select=appRoles
```

**Response:**

[image]

**Code Sample in Java:**

```java
GraphServiceClient graphClient = GraphServiceClient.builder().authenticationProvider( authProvider ).buildClient();

ServicePrincipalCollectionPage servicePrincipals = graphClient.servicePrincipals()
.buildRequest()
.filter("appId eq '00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000'")
.select("appRoles")
.get();
```

**Reference:**

[List appRoleAssignments granted to a service principal  | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/serviceprincipal-list-approleassignments?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)

Comment: Thanks but the query to check appRole names is giving entire list of appRoles. How to filter it for particular IDs?